# F# equivalent of `is` keyword in C#?

Tags: types, f#, keyword, language-comparisons

My first F# day. If I have this:

```
let cat = Animal()
```

Now how do I check at later stage if `cat` `is` `Animal`?

In C#

```
bool b = cat is Animal;
```

In F#?

Comment: `let b = cat :? Animal`

Comment: @ildjarn You should add that as an answer instead of a comment, so it can be accepted.

Comment: @Jack : On a mobile so I can't give a thorough answer. Feel free. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn thanks, I knew it had something to do with `:?`, but did not get the syntax right!

Comment: You can pattern match on type too. Check other SO question [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679503/how-to-perform-multiple-styles-of-pattern-matching

Comment: @PrzemysławLewandowski, yes. Its my own question too.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*@ildjarn deserves the credit here for answering first, but I'm submitting the answer here so it can be accepted.*

The F# equivalent of the C# `is` keyword is `:?`. For example:

```
let cat = Animal()
if cat :? Animal then
    printfn "cat is an animal."
else
    printfn "cat is not an animal."
```

Answer (score 9):

For demonstration only (don't define an `is` function):

```
let is<'T> (x: obj) = x :? 'T

type Animal() = class end
type Cat() = inherit Animal()

let cat = Cat()
cat |> is<Animal> //true
```

Comment: Daniel, can you tell me what is `|>` ? Why should one include it before a function call? Does it have a name?

Comment: It's called the forward pipe operator. It applies the operand on the left as the last argument to the function on the right. ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340273.aspx))

Comment: Daniel, why wouldn't you define is as a function, looks pretty useful to me?

Comment: @sacha: Given that there's a built-in type test operator (`:?`), `is<'T>` doesn't provide much value. Compare `cat is<Animal>` to `cat :? Animal`.

Comment: @Daniel : Yeah I guess, I think Is<T> reads better personally, but I guess once you are familiar with all the weird FSharp operators, its fine.

Comment: You're right. It requires translation, i.e., reading `:?` as "is"—much the same as reading `>` as "greater than."

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm late. If you try to test the type of a collection in fsi with :?
it will give an error, if the item types do not match. E.g.

```
let squares = seq { for x in 1 .. 15 -> x * x }  
squares :? list<int> ;;   // will give false  
squares :? list<string> ;; // error FS0193: Type constraint mismatch
```

Wrapping in a function like Daniels is<'T> works.