# How to perform multiple styles of pattern matching?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

Just started to play with F#. As terrible as I'm with it now, I do not to know to search for a similar thread too.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
let test animal =
    if animal :? Cat //testing for type
    then "cat" 
    elif animal :? Dog //testing for type
    then "dog" 
    elif animal = unicorn //testing value equality
    then "impossible"
    else "who cares"
```

Basically it involves type test pattern matching along with other conditional checks. I can get the first part (type checking) done like this:

```
let test(animal:Animal) =
    match animal with
    | :? Cat as cat -> "cat"
    | :? Dog as dog -> "cat"
    | _ -> "who cares"
```

**1.** Is there a way I can incorporate the equality checking (as in the first example) as well in the above type test pattern matching?

**2.** Is such multiple kinds of checks performed in a single pattern matching construct generally frowned upon in F# circle?

Comment: 1. Research `when`. 2. F# is primarily functional, and you're abusing OOP constructs (this would be frowned upon in any language, not just F#); use a DU instead.

Comment: @ildjarn of course it is. I'm asking is it particularly bad to use pattern matching for this (anyway bad) kind of thing. I mean, is it worse to use pattern matching than simple if else here? *(I was converting some old hobby code in C# to F# btw, just learning)*

Comment: 1. `"? Cat as cat when cat=unicorn` 2. This is a very bad idea.

Comment: @JohnPalmer could you make it a workable answer? Getting F# syntax correct is not my strength at this point :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the equivalent using pattern matching:

```
let test (animal:Animal) =
  match animal with
  | :? Cat as cat -> "cat"
  | :? Dog as dog -> "dog"
  | _ when animal = unicorn -> "impossible"
  | _ -> "who cares"
```

I wouldn't say this is frowned upon. It's sometimes needed with OOP and it's already better (more concise, clearer) than the C# equivalent.

Comment: Oops, thanks Daniel, sometimes its hard to get the syntax subtleties right among many notations in a language like F# :) Searching for `when` keyword took me to here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233203.aspx, I think it has nothing to do with then `when` in your answer. That's why I find it hard.

Comment: I agree its more readable than `if-else`. Just realised how flexible pattern matching is in F# now :)

Comment: [Pattern Matching on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx) covers `when`.

Comment: Daniel, oh yes I see it now. I had seen that link and `when` there, but only with your example I understood it. Thanks.