# A function that can check if a given list is a string list using f#

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-data, c#-to-f#, f#-3.0

How can I write a function that will check a given list and return true if the list is a string list? At the moment what I have is that it returns true for any list it is given.

```
let rec checklist list =
match list with 
| x :: xs ->  true
| _ -> false

checklist ["1";"2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is homework.

I suggest you first write a function to determine if an object is a string or not ([this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16677345/7419043)), then look through the `List` module for a suitable function to test forall elements in your list.